# Mongo not using enough RAM, and is slow

Tags: mongodb

Our Production Mongo appears to be behaving weirdly. As far as I have read, Mongo should eat up all the available RAM to cache Index and Data in memory but in our case it is not doing so.
Our Production Box is 16 GB RAM, 4 Core machine and Mongo is the only process running.

The DB Stats are here:

```
rep_score:SECONDARY> db.stats()
{
"db" : "pqrdb",
"collections" : 11,
"objects" : 31679474,
"avgObjSize" : 340.39471286676036,
"dataSize" : 10783525456,
"storageSize" : 15890214848,
"numExtents" : 68,
"indexes" : 28,
"indexSize" : 6493632656,
"fileSize" : 36423335936,
"nsSizeMB" : 16,
"dataFileVersion" : {
    "major" : 4,
    "minor" : 5
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

The DB Status Along with working set is here:

```
rep_pqr:SECONDARY> db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1, workingSet: 1})
{
"host" : "pqr02.abc123xyz.com",
"version" : "2.4.3",
"process" : "mongod",
"pid" : 1765,
"uptime" : 16494178,
"uptimeMillis" : NumberLong("16494178317"),
"uptimeEstimate" : 16316693,
"localTime" : ISODate("2014-06-06T03:37:04.640Z"),
"asserts" : {
    "regular" : 0,
    "warning" : 0,
    "msg" : 0,
    "user" : 57,
    "rollovers" : 0
},
"backgroundFlushing" : {
    "flushes" : 274902,
    "total_ms" : 5126493,
    "average_ms" : 18.648438352576555,
    "last_ms" : 1,
    "last_finished" : ISODate("2014-06-06T03:36:45.261Z")
},
"connections" : {
    "current" : 217,
    "available" : 9383,
    "totalCreated" : NumberLong(2519815)
},
"cursors" : {
    "totalOpen" : 0,
    "clientCursors_size" : 0,
    "timedOut" : 24
},
"dur" : {
    "commits" : 30,
    "journaledMB" : 0,
    "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0,
    "compression" : 0,
    "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
    "earlyCommits" : 0,
    "timeMs" : {
        "dt" : 3067,
        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
        "writeToJournal" : 0,
        "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
        "remapPrivateView" : 0
    }
},
"extra_info" : {
    "note" : "fields vary by platform",
    "heap_usage_bytes" : 174014128,
    "page_faults" : 1298264
},
"globalLock" : {
    "totalTime" : NumberLong("16494178317000"),
    "lockTime" : NumberLong(1108422630),
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    }
},
"indexCounters" : {
    "accesses" : 501846311,
    "hits" : 501920431,
    "misses" : 0,
    "resets" : 0,
    "missRatio" : 0
},
"locks" : {
    "." : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "R" : NumberLong(482761990),
            "W" : NumberLong(1108422630)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "R" : NumberLong(400518420),
            "W" : NumberLong("2451617010")
        }
    },
    "admin" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {

        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

        }
    },
    "local" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(42854138),
            "w" : NumberLong(655587832)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(42174429),
            "w" : NumberLong(576262708)
        }
    },
    "pqrdb" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong("5130410609200"),
            "w" : NumberLong("6239642518")
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong("377327866372"),
            "w" : NumberLong(1307459582)
        }
    },
    "test" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(4940871),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(858298),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "config" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(329952),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(92079),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
},
"network" : {
    "bytesIn" : NumberLong("3756675627064"),
    "bytesOut" : NumberLong("5878336152210"),
    "numRequests" : 15687951094
},
"opcounters" : {
    "insert" : 0,
    "query" : 569628851,
    "update" : 0,
    "delete" : 0,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 1031917
},
"opcountersRepl" : {
    "insert" : 1109498,
    "query" : 0,
    "update" : 2961924,
    "delete" : 13301046,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 2
},
"recordStats" : {
    "accessesNotInMemory" : 1062878,
    "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 968878,
    "config" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
    },
    "local" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 4950,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 3
    },
    "pqrdb" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 1057928,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 968875
    },
    "test" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
    }
},
"repl" : {
    "setName" : "rep_pqr",
    "ismaster" : false,
    "secondary" : true,
    "hosts" : [
        "pqr02.abc123xyz.com:27017",
        "pqr04.abc123xyz.com:27017",
        "pqr03.abc123xyz.com:27017",
        "pqr01.abc123xyz.com:27017"
    ],
    "primary" : "pqr01.abc123xyz.com:27017",
    "me" : "pqr02.abc123xyz.com:27017"
},
"workingSet" : {
    "note" : "thisIsAnEstimate",
    "pagesInMemory" : 30687,
    "computationTimeMicros" : 11141,
    "overSeconds" : 818
},
"writeBacksQueued" : false,
"mem" : {
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 2263,
    "virtual" : 68782,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 33809,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 67618
},
"metrics" : {
    "document" : {
        "deleted" : NumberLong(0),
        "inserted" : NumberLong(1),
        "returned" : NumberLong("13803172637"),
        "updated" : NumberLong(587)
    },
    "getLastError" : {
        "wtime" : {
            "num" : 0,
            "totalMillis" : 0
        },
        "wtimeouts" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "operation" : {
        "fastmod" : NumberLong(587),
        "idhack" : NumberLong(1487),
        "scanAndOrder" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "queryExecutor" : {
        "scanned" : NumberLong("66334958515")
    },
    "record" : {
        "moves" : NumberLong(3485)
    },
    "repl" : {
        "apply" : {
            "batches" : {
                "num" : 654440,
                "totalMillis" : 7507090
            },
            "ops" : NumberLong(17372470)
        },
        "buffer" : {
            "count" : NumberLong(0),
            "maxSizeBytes" : 268435456,
            "sizeBytes" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "network" : {
            "bytes" : NumberLong("2569491405"),
            "getmores" : {
                "num" : 3796775,
                "totalMillis" : 8293013651
            },
            "ops" : NumberLong(17372470),
            "readersCreated" : NumberLong(45069)
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "insert" : {
                "num" : 17372470,
                "totalMillis" : 225883
            },
            "insertBytes" : NumberLong("2499449845")
        },
        "preload" : {
            "docs" : {
                "num" : 2961924,
                "totalMillis" : 145876
            },
            "indexes" : {
                "num" : 54749109,
                "totalMillis" : 1204175
            }
        }
    },
    "ttl" : {
        "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
        "passes" : NumberLong(274897)
    }
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

While Here is the Top Output:

```
Tasks: 115 total,   1 running, 114 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.6%us,  3.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 78.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.2%st
Mem:  15343792k total,  7955056k used,  7388736k free,   622104k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,     4172k used,  4190128k free,  6705928k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                           
1765 mongod    20   0 67.2g 2.2g 2.0g S 85.8 15.1  83080:23 mongod
```

Mongo Stat:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       set repl       time 
*0   3121     *0     *0       0     4|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0   733k     1m   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:14 
*0   2378     *0     *0       0     7|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   576k     1m   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:15 
*0    582     *0     *0       0     6|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     2|0   128k   178k   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:16 
*0   2809     *0     *0       0     6|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   663k     1m   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:17 
*0   1328     *0     *0       0     5|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   315k   628k   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:18 
*0    884     *0     *0       0     4|0       0    33g  67.2g  2.21g      0 pqrdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   211k   447k   217 rep_pqr  SEC   09:22:19
```

Now, my worry is the index is around 6GB and Data is around 10GB but my "res" memory is around 2.2G and overall RAM usage is around 800 MB. Although, the stats does not show any faults or read/write queues the overall performance of DB seem to be slow. I would also like to point here that, the peak time usage makes around 8500 requests per second with around 300 connections to the host. And at that rate CPU seem to go up to 210% with very little/No upswing in RAM.

There are a lot of queries which take more than 100ms for the first time and 0ms, if we fire the same query again. Our system is such the input data to the query changes almost everytime and hence the response of lot of queries is beyond 100ms.

For example:

Fri Jun  6 08:41:02.419 [conn2355330] query pqrdb.ruleUnit query: { banned: true, paramValue: "SDL810574901", type: "prodcode-svcs", paymentMethodCode: "cash-on-delivery", enabled: true, synched: true, startDate: { $lte: new Date(1402024262311) }, $or: [ { endDate: { $gt: new Date(1402024262311) } }, { endDate: { $exists: false } } ] } ntoreturn:10 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:107190 nreturned:0 reslen:20 107ms

and

Fri Jun  6 08:41:02.421 [conn2355433] query pqrdb.ruleUnit query: { vendorType: "drop-ship-vendor", banned: true, paramValue: "mobiles-mobile-phones", type: "category-svcs", paymentMethodCode: "cash-on-delivery", enabled: true, synched: true, startDate: { $lte: new Date(1402024262312) }, $or: [ { endDate: { $gt: new Date(1402024262312) } }, { endDate: { $exists: false } } ] } ntoreturn:10 ntoskip:0 nscanned:30 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:109838 nreturned:1 reslen:551 109ms

Free -m output:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         14984       7770       7213          0        607       6549
-/+ buffers/cache:        612      14371
Swap:         4095          4       4091
```

**To Summarize:**

```
Host RAM: 16 GB
Index: 6.04 GB
Data: 10 GB
FileSize: 35 GB
Mongo Takes RAM: 800 MB
Mongo Res Memory: 2.2 GB
No Faults in Mongo Stats
Peak Time request: 8500 requests per second
Number of Connections: 300 @ peak
```

Main problem, why is Mongo not eating the remaining 14 GB of RAM. If it starts taking full RAM my opinion is that the performance will improved - will it?

Otherwise also: Any pointers on how we can improve the overall performance of our Mongo would be great.

Comment: please post the readahead settings (sudo blockdev --report) for your data volume, and I'd also recommend having a look at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9415 and taking a look at this tool: http://eng.wish.com/mongomem-memory-usage-by-collection-in-mongodb/

Comment: can you share the explain plans for the queries? what we are looking is a secondary?

Comment: I had the same issue: Windows Server 2008 R2, 16 Gb RAM, Mongo 2.4.3. Mongo uses only 2 Gb of RAM and generates a lot of page faults. Queries are very slow. Disk is idle, memory is free. Found no other solution than upgrade to 2.6.5. It helped.

Comment: Is it possible that the OS is 32bit?

Comment: I am asking because 2GiB are roughly 2.2GB.. Or maybe you run a 32bit version on a 64bit OS?